# PayPal Adaptive - 4 Way Payments

Tags: paypal, payment

We're looking to specifically find out if PayPal Adaptive Payments can be setup to split 4 ways?

We currently use PayPal Adaptive Payments on one of our other sites and it does a great job splitting the payments up between two recipients.

However, on another website that we are working on, we want to split the payments between 3 recipients.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Parallel Payments will allow up to 6 receivers, and chained payments will allow up to 9 receivers.

Details on that available [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).

**Chained Payments**

> You can have at most one primary receiver and 1-9 secondary receivers.

**Parallel Payments**

> A parallel payment is a payment from a sender that is split directly among 2-6 receivers.

Comment: Andrew, two other question with regard to the Chained and Parallel Payments...which option should we choose if there will be a total of 3 recipients and with each recipient receiving a different percentage amount of the payments?  and  Is it possible to setup a script that will automatically populate the PayPal Email Field of the 3rd Recipient from their referral links over to our site?